# Is there a way to automate generation of figures from Avogadro?

Tags: visualization-software, avogadro

I have a collection of molecules represented by SMILES codes, along with their corresponding 3D coordinates. I want to efficiently generate figures for these structures using Avogadro. Ideally, I would like to set the visualization parameters (e.g., rendering style, orientation) once and then apply these settings to multiple molecules to ensure consistent and reproducible visualizations. In VMD, I am familiar with using state files to achieve this. How can I achieve a similar reproducibility feature in Avogadro for generating figures of multiple molecules with consistent visualization settings?

Comment: Hi @Hemanth Haridas, have you considered using the Atomic Simulation Environment combined with povray rendering as reported in https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/faq.html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is in the latest development version (1.98) as I discussed on the [Avogadro forum](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/t/images-for-a-whole-directory/4430/2?u=ghutchis).

I shared an [example script](https://gist.github.com/ghutchis/940b3f094969c515d02074bd9cb92c2b) for exporting screenshots for a folder of `*.xyz` files.

- Launch Avogadro2 (latest nightly builds)
- Run the script in a directory of .xyz files
- It will load the files one-by-one into Avogadro and save a PNG image

Please share feedback on the Avogadro forum -- we are [interested in other automation tasks](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/t/tasks-for-automation/3951?u=ghutchis) (e.g., rendering X orbital or surface, etc.)

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11488/5